# Is there a way to make LitHtml attributes optional?

Tags: lit-element, lit-html

I'm not talking about boolean attributes, attributes like `class` if you don't want to add an empty class attribute if there's no CSS class.

```
html`<span class=${hasClass ? 'my-class' : ''}></span>`
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an [`ifDefined`](https://lit.dev/docs/api/directives/#ifDefined) directive that does what you want. If the value is `undefined` the attribute won't be rendered.

```js
import {ifDefined} from 'lit-html/directives/if-defined';

html`<span class=${ifDefined(hasClass ? 'my-class' : undefined)}></span>`
```